# incrementing static member of a class in main - C++

Tags: c++

I am getting this error `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘++’ token 29 | std::cout<<x::foo::++z;`

basically I am trying to increment `z` from foo in main

```
#include <iostream>

namespace x {
  class foo {
  public:
    void bar1(foo& f) {
      ++x;     
    }
    friend void bar2(foo& f);

    int x;
    int y;
    static  int z;
  };

  int x::foo::z=15;
  void bar2(foo& f) {
    f.y++;       // Error: y not in scope
  }
}

int main() {
  x::foo a;
  ++a.x=5;
  std::cout << ++a.x << std::endl;
  std::cout << x::foo::z;
  std::cout << x::foo::++z; //throws error
  return 0;
}
```

z is static member.

my question is how to access and increment static member `z`?
also can declaration be done outside class in C++, somehow?

Comment: Can't reproduce `Error: y not in scope`. I only get an error on `x::foo::++z`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what is `error messages verbatim`? Can u please tell

Comment: Deleted that comment before you replied, after Philipp formatted your code for you... I was asking for exact error messages. You say `"Error: y not in scope"`, but is this the exact message you get? I get no error on this line, and you accepted the answer that doesn't address this line at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the **operation** first (the `++` operator), then specify the **object** on which to call the operator (the `x::foo::z`):

```
// Increment the x::foo::z
++x::foo::z; 
// Equivalent to ++(x::foo::z)
```